# REST API design resource time bound

Tags: scala, rest, api, spray

Recently I was asked to build a RESTful API that would retrieve Offers which are time bound (have an expiry time), such that subsequent querying on the resource should reflect the changes.

My approach (POST) was to send a $timestamp value within the object body so it is part of the request:

> { "itemID":1, 
>   "itemName":"item1",
>   "itemTimestamp":"{{$timestamp}}",
>   "itemPrice":4.65,
>   "offerPeriod":"4m",
>   "offerTimeLeft":"NA" }

Note now that the offerPeriod key: "4m" corresponds to 4 minutes life time of that specific resource.

I have designed the API in such a way, that subsequent querying to that particular resource would first validate/check if the query time is within the expiry period, if it is then update the timeleft value, else DELETE the resource.

Could someone highlight how / where have I violated REST constraints.

https://github.com/Datahman/ScalaRESTSpray

Many thanks.

Comment: On `GET` request you are doing some operations to the resource that actually are not side-effects free when it comes to the client - in particular you are deleting a resource with `GET` which should be idempotent. In you API not only `GET` is not idempotent but it influences the resource state. What was the original scenario for the API? Why the time of resource to live is not measured in the background?

Comment: @Opal Thanks for your response. Ah ! I see my mistake in the implementation now.

Comment: If you find my answer useful may I add it as an answer?

Comment: I am not sure what that means @Opal, adding to ?

Comment: May I add my comment as an answer for you to accept it?